# Hard disk keeps turning off when "Battery Saver" mode is on, despite all setting

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, battery-life

I have changed all settings regarding hard disk turn off time to "never" in all power plans.
Still when Windows 10's Battery Saver feature is turned on, the hard disk keeps shutting down after a few seconds of idle time, and then spins back up to do some windows task.
How can I turn this feature off without stopping Battery Saver. I want to keep using Battery Saver because it gives extended battery life by stopping background tasks, but I don't want to kill my hard drive prematurely.
I am looking for a possible registry hack or group policy change, but I can't find any.

Comment: What is shown in ``Advanced power settings`` in your current ``Power plan`` regarding to the time when the hard disk should be turned off?

Comment: Never for battery and unplugged

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link below to configure Power Saver feature, since you need to keep hard disk running, I think you should  always allowed some apps run in the background.
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2647-battery-saver-turn-off-windows-10-a.html

Also, make sure your has configured 0 minute on Turn off hard disk after which in Power Options.
[image]
Regards

Comment: I have already done both of those things, my main hard disk is still spinning down after 15 minutes and then spins up and down every 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes It does not work for me too. It seems like a bug.